# Magento 2: How can I change the Value in the Url of the paypal Button?

Tags: price, url, paypal, paypal-express

My problem is happening every time I click on the express checkout with PayPal.

I get an error that the link is not working, I found out that when you click the button the value is for example`"(1,000)"` and Paypal does not recognize the`","` in the value.

If anyone would be so kind as to guide me or explain to me how can I change that so when it adds the value to the Paypal link is only like `1000 USD` instead of `1,000`.